# Snow Leopard Hangs at Login Window

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, freeze, login-screen

I've had an issue for the past few months, but I rarely restart so it hasn't caused too much trouble.

Basically, when I start up my Mac (iMac10,1 - 3.06GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, OS X 10.6.3) everything proceeds as usual until I reach the login window.

The login window displays normally, but keyboard and mouse input seem to be ignored. This condition persists for around 5 minutes at which time everything goes back to normal.

While the login window is frozen my second monitor appears entirely blue, the second monitor receives a background as soon as the login window becomes responsive.

If I startup while holding SHIFT the problem still occurs, but the freeze is much shorter.

Looking through my logs I see no activity during the time that the login window is frozen.

I've attempted to repair disk permissions, and gone through every possible maintenance option in Cocktail.

Comment: Does this happen when the second monitor isn't used/plugged in?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test, I had a lot to get done today. I'll try it next time I restart.

Comment: I tried with the second monitor disconnected and the problem still occurred.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? Have you upgraded to 10.6.8 or 10.7.3 by now? Does the problem still occur?

Comment: Apple eventually just gave me a new computer. I'm guessing that there was a logic board issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the file system/ hardware?  If you're booting in safe mode and you've still got a problem
Disk Utility -> Verify disk.

Also reboot with your system disks and hold down 'd' on the newer macs and run the hardware check.

It sounds like the caching on start up is causing a problem, whether it's the file system or the OS is hard to say.

Comment: I've tried safe mode, used disk utility, and run the hardware check. Can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Marking this as accepted as it's the closest answer -- Apple eventually gave me a new computer, so I'm assuming that there was some hardware problem that the hardware check didn't identify.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wild guess, but perhaps it's attempting to contact something via the network that it can't find?  Perhaps trying to auto-mount a share that's not available, or load a font that was activated over the network.

It might be worth taking a good look at anything that `launchd` is starting up as well.

Does your system log in automatically?

Comment: No, I manually login.

Comment: I tried looking for anything on the network that might be holding up the startup, but couldn't find anything. I also tried looking though all of the LaunchAgents/Daemons but found nothing there either.